# SQL Server - Question about Inheritance in Database Schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having problems understanding the class table inheritance structure that you can implement using database tables. [Info on class table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database). I have a use case where I have quite different types of persons that I need to model, but they have very minor differences. For example, all of these persons, like Student, Professor and so on, have a surname and a lastname. My first thought was to move theses attributes into a different table inside a base table like you would do in Object Oriented Programming. Here to illustrate further:

[image]

Right now, a Professor can only have one person, for example, otherwise it wouldn't make sense in my use case. Also, I have a school table that has two foreign keys, one for the Professor and one for the Student. Lets assume that a school can also have only one professor and one student. This is not the real use case that I have. This example just represents the relation in my real use case which would be too much to explain here.

What I don't understand is how you would collect data based on that. I'm trying to make a SQL Server View where I want to load the Person of the Professor and the Person of the Student from the view point of the School Table. For example:

```
SELECT 
    School.professor_id
    surname,
    lastname
FROM dbo.School AS school

INNER JOIN dbo.Professor as prof
    ON school.professor_id = prof.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Person as prof_person
    ON prof.person_id = prof_person.ID
```

I can output the surname and lastname of the professor, but now I am stuck since I can't figure out how to get the person of the student.

Comment: Join to `Person` twice.

Comment: And then? How would you write the SELECT part of the query?

Comment: Properly qualify your column names, @Florent, like you should be doing anyway.

Comment: *"The proper column name would be Person.surname"* wrong, in your above query that would error as you aliased `Person` as `prof_person`. I know the answer, but with the prior comment, I'm out

Comment: Why do you have a surname and a lastname?  Where is the firstname?

Comment: You need to learn about using nice and short *and meaningful* table aliases, they make queries much more readable. You could pick `pProf` and `pStud` as aliases for the two joins

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor Does it matter? Its about the problem here not about if I have surname lastname etc, they are just columns you know.

Comment: Yeah, it matters.  Detail is important in this game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subtype table typically shares a key with the supertype table, instead of having its own PK and a FK.  EG Student.ID is both the PK and the FK.

Then just join Student>Person in addition to Professor>Person, eg

```
SELECT 
    School.Id,
    prof_person.surname prof_surname,
    student_person.surname student_surname
FROM dbo.School AS school
INNER JOIN dbo.Professor as prof
    ON school.professor_id = prof.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Person as prof_person
    ON prof.ID = prof_person.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Student as student
    ON school.student_id = student.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Person as student_person
    ON student.ID = student_person.ID
```

INNER JOIN is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), so no need for special ordering or parentheses.